# Assembly InvokeMember try{} catch()

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

we're currently working on a program which has an open C# API interface. Now, imagine you have the following C# script:

```
int[] Test = { 0, 3 };

private void Test()
{
    Debug.Log(Test[4].ToString()); //Exception!!
}
```

Compiling works, however, if we now try to `Invoke` the `Test Void` it will fail. It should obviously fail, but we want to catch the Exception, so our **whole Application** doesn't freeze.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:/Our/Path/To/Dll.dll");

Type type = assembly.GetType("ClassApplication1.Test");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

type.InvokeMember("Test",
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn,
null,
instance,
null);
```

This popup will appear in Visual Studio 2012 if we're debugging, without debugging our Application simply crashes completly.

[image: nn]

[image: nn]

//Edit:

I know that the `Debug.Log(Test[4].ToString()); //Exception!!` is wrong and will call an excetpion (!!!). It was wanted. Putting a try {} block through that will work, but keep in mind that the scripts are 3rd-party made. I don't have my hands on this, but atleast I wan't that our application is EATING the errors (and DISPLAYS them in a richTextBox), instead of throwing them (=Application crashes).

**TLDR: I want to prevent 3rd party assemblies which i load into my assembly to make my program crash**

Comment: Test has a max size of 1 the way your initializing it. You are trying to access the 4th index...Change it to 0 or 1 depending on which number you want.

Comment: Try doing a `catch (Exception ex)` and see if the type is really `IndexOutOfRange`, or if that exception is being wrapped in something else by `InvokeMember`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it, you simply need to catch the exception thrown by `InvokeMember`:

```
try
{
    type.InvokeMember("Test", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn, null, instance, null);
}
catch(TargetInvocationException e)
{
    // e.InnerException will be IndexOutOfRangeException in your example
}
catch(Exception e)
{  // one of the other exceptions
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx) for all of the possible exceptions that can lead to the second block.  You probably want to just wrap all of the code (starting from loading the assembly) in a try block, since those can fail also.

You should also investigate [AppDomains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx), they are the "right" way to do isolation like this.  They hook into the CLR to provide more protection than you can possibly manage on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] Test = { 0, 3 };
```

This line sets `Test` array size to 2, so the only items you can take from it are:

```
Test[0] // == 0
Test[1] // == 3
```

That's why `Debug.Log(Test[4].ToString());` throws an exception.

To catch it you have to use `try`/`catch` block when calling `Test` method:

```
try
{
    Test();
}
catch(IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I know that the `Debug.Log(Test[4].ToString()); //Exception!!` is wrong and will call an excetpion. It was wanted. Putting a try {} block through that will work, but keep in mind that the scripts are 3rd-party made. I don't have my hands on this, but atleast I wan't that our application is EATING the errors (and DISPLAYS them in a richTextBox), instead of throwing them (=Application crashes).

Comment: @Finn Maybe state that in your questions the first time.

Comment: If you know why the exception is being thrown and how to catch it, I have no idea what you're actually asking about ...

Comment: OK; Lets try it this way. As example: Imagine I'm writing a Browser, and the Browser allows, that people can write Add-Ons/Extensions. Now, imagine that a Add-On/Extenseion developer did a fault in his code, which appears sometimes and now imagine that it crashes the WHOLE browser instead of just printing it somewhere. - TLDR: I want to prevent 3rd party assemblies which i load into my assembly to make my program crash

Comment: Add `try`/`catch` without specifying exception type to catch all exceptions.

Comment: I did, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: is this MVC? You could make a custom action filter to catch all unhanded exception.

Comment: Surrounding the activator code with try catch should fix it why it not working for you ?